# error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, pointers

I am getting this error can anyone tell me why is this so?

```
error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if (root == n1 || root == n2)
```

Please note that it's Function problem i.e.
    you need to write your solution in the form Function(s) only.
    Driver Code to call/invoke your function would be added by GfG's Online Judge.

Here is the code:

```
/* A binary tree node
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* left, * right;
}; */
/*you are required to 
complete this function */
Node * LCA(Node* root ,int n1 ,int n2 )
{
    if(root==NULL) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(root==n1||root==n2)
    {
        return root;
    }
    Node* left=LCA(root->left,n1,n2);
    Node* right=LCA(root->right,n1,n2);
    if(root->left!=NULL&&root->right!=NULL)
    {
        return root;
    }
    if(root->left==NULL&&root->right==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return left!=NULL?left:right;
   //Your code here 
}
```

Comment: Does the error tell you nothing?

Comment: Could it be any clearer?

Comment: @LogicStuff yaa it points to "if(root==n1||root==n2)" this line...

Comment: You might be trying to compare data not the whole root

Comment: It has some words too, and they form a sentence.

Comment: @SumitRaj What else does it tell you...

Comment: @HariomSingh ya how to do that...?

Comment: @Borgleader Compilation Error:
Compilation Error
7eb0e3f40308642cfd82545f2fb722d3.cpp: In function 'Node* LCA(Node*, int, int)':
7eb0e3f40308642cfd82545f2fb722d3.cpp:100:14: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if(root==n1||root==n2)
              ^
7eb0e3f40308642cfd82545f2fb722d3.cpp:100:24: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if(root==n1||root==n2)
                        ^

Comment: Are you really sure that a warning about ISO C++ is related to C language and needs that language tag?

Comment: Comparing a pointer and an `int` makes no sense, which is what the compiler is trying to tell you. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @DavidBowling i am trying to find Lowest common ancestor of the given two nodes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(root==n1||root==n2)
```

Comparison is wrong as `n1` and `n2` are `int` type and `root` is of `Node*` type

You might be trying to compare with `int` data

if your `Node` implementation is

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

as your function does `Node *root;`

you could do

```
if (root->data == n1 || root->data == n2)
```

After reading the link provided your solution

Just for other user the link provided by the user has following question

> Given a Binary Tree and 2 nodes value n1 and n2, your task is to find the lowest common ancestor of the two nodes. You are required to complete the function LCA. You should not read any input from stdin/console. There are multiple test cases. For each test case, this method will be called individually.
>
> Input: The task is to complete the method LCA which takes 3 arguments,
>   root of the Tree and two nodes value  n1 and n2. The struct node has
>   a data part which stores the data, pointer to left child and pointer
>   to right child. There are multiple test cases. For each test case,
>   this method will be called individually.
>
> Output: The function should return the node which is the least common
>   ancestor of the two nodes n1 and n2 .
>
> Constraints: 1 <= T <= 30, 1 <= Number of nodes <= 100 and  1 <= Data of a node <= 1000

```
Node *LCA(Node *root, int n1, int n2)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (root->data == n1 || root->data == n2)
        return root;

    Node *left  = LCA(root->left, n1, n2);
    Node *right = LCA(root->right, n1, n2);

    if (left && right)
        return root;

    if (left)
        return left;
    else
        return right;
}
```

Example Explanation

Example:

```
Input
1
2
1 2 L 1 3 R
2 3 

Output 
1

In above example there is one  test case which represent a tree with 3 nodes and 2 edges where root is 1, left child of 1 is 2 and right child of 1 is 3.
```

Comment: isn't there any way to do that?

Comment: tried your method but it fails for one test case:Input:
30 
0 1 L 0 2 R  1 3 L 1 4 R  2 5 L 2 6 R  3 7 L 3 8 R  4 9 L 4 10 R  5 11 L 5 12 R  6 13 L 6 14 R  7 15 L 7 16 R  8 17 L 8 18 R  9 19 L 9 20 R  10 21 L 10 22 R  11 23 L 11 24 R  12 25 L 12 26 R  13 27 L 13 28 R  14 29 L 14 30 R  
30 30

Its Correct output is:
30

And Your Output is:
0

Comment: Send me the link where you are trying this  @SumitRaj

Comment: http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-in-a-binary-tree/1

Comment: can you suggest any? It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a cut / paste error: `if (root == n1 || root == n2)` should have been:

```
if (root->data == n1 || root->data == n2)
```

I'm afraid this programming test is very low quality.

Comment: i modified it but gives me another error "In function `main':
604969153f33896cb3ff928905ff9676.cpp:(.text+0x277): undefined reference to `LCA(Node*, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: @SumitRaj Can you please post the whole code , so that we can understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @HariomSingh actually its only a function complete program so i have to complete the function only...

Comment: @SumitRaj: can you post the rest of the code? There must be some other indications you are not giving.

Comment: @SumitRaj: what is a *function completion program*?

Comment: @chqrlie here is the link:http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-in-a-binary-tree/1

Comment: @chqrlie it means you only have to complete the function rest it will be judged online

Comment: @SumitRaj: completing is one thing, copying the existing part is another: you forgot to copy the `->data` parts in your attempt ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your line is `if (root == n1 || root == n2)`. The error message is “ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer”. In this context, a “comparison” is any of `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=`. You have two of them on the referenced line; `root == n1` and `root == n2`.

If you look at where those variables are declared, you see that `root` is a `Node*`, which means “pointer to `Node`”, and `n1` and `n2` are `int`s, which stands for “integer”. Thus both of the comparisons try to compare a *pointer* (`root`) to an *integer* (`n1` or `n2`), which the error tells you is not allowed.

You can think of a pointer as a variable’s phone number (the usual metaphor is address, but phone number works better in this case) and an `int` as just a number. You can treat a phone number as an `int` (for example, if the phone number is 555-867-5309, you can pretend it’s the number 5,558,675,309), but you rarely want to do this so C++ makes you be explicit when you try. What you’re doing is like asking “is the phone number `root` the same as this number I was passed”; that is theoretically a thing you might want to do, but it’s *probably not what you actually want*.

In this case, what you want to do is (probably; I don’t know the problem for sure) to metaphorically “call” `root` and ask what the number it knows is, by getting `root->data`. Thus the line you want is probably some variant of

```
if (root->data == n1 || root->data == n2)
```

Note that the rest of your function looks weird, and I think you might have other problems, but this will let you focus on those by getting past the compiler error.

---

Not part of the answer, but information on how to use Stack OVerflow which doesn’t fit in a comment:

The reason you got downvoted so much is probably because you asked why the error was occurring, when that’s not really quite what you wanted. The error message is pretty clear about this; I explain it in more detail in the first two paragraphs of my answer, but most C++ programmers will already know most of that, this particular error message was relatively clear, and it isn’t clear which part you don’t understand. If part of it was confusing, you’d do better to ask about *that specific part* (like “What sort of comparison is it talking about?” or “Why is that not allowed?”); in addition, since you also want information on how to *fix* it, it is helpful if you explain what you want to do and why.